# MVC ASP.Net Javascript - How do I use a javascript function to hide a button if Url has no id

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my Javascript code that goes to the url with the correct id from model but I am not sure how to hide it if the url has no model id.

```
 function lnkBack_Confirm() {
    var bResponse = confirm('Are you sure you want to go back to the Details Page?');

    if (bResponse === true) {
        ////console.log("lnkBack_Confirm clciked.");
        var url = '@Url.Action("NewHireDetails", "Home", new { id = Model.ID })';
        window.location.href = url;
    }

    return bResponse;
}
```

All I would like to do is hide it if the url has no id = Model.ID.  I am not sure how to do this.  Can someone please help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `location.href`?  Or, since this is apparently Razor, you could ask about the route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can look at model values in your script.  something like this should work for you

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if('@Model.ID' == ''){
        $('.btnClass').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: This seems like a Rube Goldberg kind of way to go about it.